# new File not found in Webcontent. Need to refresh

Tags: java, tomcat

Hello i have a java backend running on tomcat. java creates a .txt File that is saved locally in the Webcontent Folder. But the file is not found on the client side, altought it exists on the Webserver. After a refresh of my java workspace the file is found. Is there a way to tell tomcat to refresh / redeploy using java?

greetings!

Comment: give some code; explain better;

Comment: Where is this "refresh" taking place? In Eclipse?

Comment: Yes refresh in eclipse manually. i want the effect of this manual refresh made by java code.

Comment: You need to elaborate "But the file is not found on the client side," in **much more** detail. How is the client side trying to access the file? By a file download servlet? The word "client side" is the most confusing here, it simply doesn't fit in the remnant of your story. Do you for instance know what it means? Don't you rather mean just the "Eclipse workspace" here? If so, then this is an Eclipse problem rather than Java/Tomcat problem. If not, then say so and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not see your WebContents folder, but a copy create by the Tomcat server connector.   Refreshing updates the copy.

What generates the .txt file?  A separate program or code embedded in your web application?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of cases where the app would have to generate the file to be immediately available to the browser. For example, an image upload window. When the server creates the file from within WTP, it will have to also create the file at the published location where Tomcat is expected to pick it up. Open the server properties, tomcat arguments, catalina root parameter to find out where this location is. When the application is deployed this functionality will need to be disabled, of course.